# How can i format date column with format "Sat Aug 16 2001" using R?

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with a date column using a specific date pattern, where the format is "Sat Aug 15 1992", for example.
I tried to use `as.Date("Sat Aug 15 1992","%Y-%m-%d")` but it returns only NA. How can I make R understand my column as a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `?strptime`, you can use :

```
as.Date("Sat Aug 15 1992","%a %b %d %Y")
#[1] "1992-08-15"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
as.Date("Sat Aug 15 1992",format="%Y-%m-%d")
```